# Al comenzar a depurar en visual studio code una aplicación de flutter, no me aparece el registro de eventos de la app en la pestaña debug console

Tags: flutter, vscode

Al comenzar a depurar en visual studio code, no me aparece el registro de eventos en la pestaña **debug console** , se ejecuta la app en mi celular fisico pero al interaccionar con la app en el celular, no muestra los eventos en el debug console, espero puedan ayudarme y gracias por su tiempo.
Adjunto imagenes para mas detalle.

[image: Esto me muestra al ejecutar la app y sigue asi aún despues de interactuar con la app]

Esto deberia mostrarme

[image: Esta es una captura de lo que desearia que me muestre al interactuar con la app]

Answer (score 0):

Para la computadora es más difícil poder depurar y obtener todos los eventos desde el celular ya pasa la información por un cable en vez de ser un emulador, pero si quieres obtener más información cuando ejecutas tu app, tienes a tu disposición el depurador interno del VS code con `F5/Debug -> Start Debugging` que tienes breakpoints, todas las funciones en pila hechas hasta el momento del breakpoint, revisar variables, etc... al igual que tienes el [DevTool Widget Inspector](https://ciberninjas.com/flutter-dart-devtools-inspector/) de Flutter, que a mi parecer ayuda enormemente más que ver los eventos en consola. Y lo puedes abrir desde la barra de tareas que tienes para detener, avanzar, reiniciar la ejecución, aparece como una lupa con el logo de Flutter dentro.

Espero haberte ayudado con tu duda. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Askaredox, te cuento que si use el DevTool pero al hacer click en la pestaña Debugger me sale que el editor de texto lo esta utilizando y no me muestra nada. Igualmente emule un dispositivo con el AVD y al hacer correr el programa igual no me mostraba cambios en la pestaña debug console. Agregando hice correr en android studio el programa pero de igual forma no me muestra datos en el logcat y haciendo correr otro programa que no esta hecho en flutter si me muestra registros del logcat. No se que hacer... igualmente Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo.